# I think my functions could be wrong

Tags: c#

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong exactly.  I think I may be using the functions wrong.  When I run the program it doesn't ask the user what they would like to do but if I press a button, it will keep logging the menu to the console repeatedly with a single press.  Also might have a problem with my flag.  Sorry I am very new to this.

```
using System;

class Purse
{
    double check_balance(int p, int n, int d, int q)
    {
        return (p + 5 * n + 10 * d + 25 * q);
    }

    double insert(int p, int n, int d, int q)
    {
        return (p + 5 * n + 10 * d + 25 * q);
    }

    double remove(int p, int n, int d, int q)
    {

        return (p + 5 * n + 10 * d + 25 * q);
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        int p = 0, n = 0, d = 0, q = 0, pChange = 0, nChange = 0, dChange = 0, qChange = 0;
        bool flag = true; // Flag
        char menu;
        Purse myBalance = new Purse(); 

        menu = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        while (flag)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?\n1. Check Balance\n2. Deposit\n3. Withdraw\n0. Close program");

            if (menu == 1)// Check the balance
            {
                myBalance.check_balance(p, n, d, q);
                continue;
            }
            else if (menu == 2)// Deposit
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deposit how many pennies?");
                pChange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                p = p + pChange;

                Console.WriteLine("Deposit how many nickels?");
                nChange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                n = n + nChange;

                Console.WriteLine("Deposit how many dimes?");
                dChange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                d = d + dChange;

                Console.WriteLine("Deposit how many quarters?");
                qChange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                q = q + qChange;

                myBalance.insert(p, n, d, q);
                continue;
            }
            else if (menu == 3)// Withdraw
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Withdraw how many pennies?");
                pChange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                p = p - pChange;

                Console.WriteLine("Withdraw how many nickels?");
                nChange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                n = n - nChange;

                Console.WriteLine("withdraw how many dimes?");
                dChange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                d = d - dChange;

                Console.WriteLine("Withdraw how many quarters?");
                qChange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                q = q - qChange;

                myBalance.remove(p, n, d, q);
                continue;
            }
            else if(menu == 0)// close the menu
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            else// Improper input
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a menu number.");
                continue;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The program will now exit.");

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `menu == '3'` ? like putting `' '` with choice?

Comment: Print the options first, ask the menu option after.

Comment: Thank you guys! I think I got it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run the program it doesn't ask the user what they would like to do

just move `menu = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;` after `Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?\n1. Check Balance\n2. Deposit\n3. Withdraw\n0. Close program");` it should be like:

```
  while (flag)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "What would you like to do?\n1. Check Balance\n2. Deposit\n3. Withdraw\n0. Close program");

                    menu = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

> if I press a button, it will keep logging the menu to the console repeatedly with a single press.

because

1- `Console.ReadKey()` is out of your main loop.
2- you should compare `menu` value either as char like `if(menu=='0')` or its value `if(menu==48)`.

for example

```
            else if (menu == 0) // close the menu
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
```

should be changed to

```
            else if (menu == '0') // close the menu
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
```